# SQL if/else vs and/or in select with different params

Tags: sql

I wonder if there's general performance difference between dividing a Query in if/else or use a long where clause with and/or when you want to make a select on a table using different parameters? Eg.

if statements:

```
if @p1 is null and @p2 is null begin
   select * from table
end
else if @p1 is not null and @p2 is null begin
   select * from table t where t.val1 = @p1
end  
else if @p1 is null and @p2 is not null begin
   select * from table t where t.val2 = @p2
end
```

and/or statements:

```
    select * from t1
    where ( 
       (t1.val1 = @p1 or @p1 is null) 
       and
       (t1.val2 = @p2 or @p2 is null)
    )
```

I'd like to use and/or statements since it doesn't produce much code and is, in my opinion, easier to read but how much will this impact performance

Comment: Have you tried to time the two and compare the results?

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Product specific problem!)

Comment: From a readability and maintenance perspective the second query is more obvious. So unless I saw a big performance benefit in the first query I would opt for the second one. Agreeing with @mins just try them and compare (which would've probably been quicker then asking here)

Comment: I did some compares but the result varied on which alternative that was faster so i thougt i had a table that was too small to make good compares on, or maybe it had to do with some existing indexes. Just wanted to know what best praxis should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is `it depends`.  But the larger the table and the more disperate the search criteria the larger the performance degredation of using `OR` to combine two differing search behaviours.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

This basically shows that `One Query` = `One Execution Plan`, and that in turn means that appropriate indexes ***can not*** be correctly used in all cases.

Although the article is specific to MS-SQL-Server, it is actually a generic principle across all of the RDBMS that I have ever worked on.

For fact tables, or anything large, use `IF` or `Dynamic SQL`.  For anything small or trivial, use concise maintainable code.